# Alert Notification "not found" after search string on page HTML

Tags: javascript, html

i have this search code html

```
<form method="" action="">
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukan No Hp yg Akan Dicari.." >
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                <input type="button" id="submit_form" onclick="checkInput()" value="Cari" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</form>
```

and this my JS code

```
<script>
    function checkInput() {
        var query = document.getElementById('search').value;
        window.find(query);
        return true; 

        }
</script>
```

i want to add alert notification... 
if search the string not found in my page

Comment: Where do you want to search for the inputted string? Entire page innerHTML, textContent, or what? (just access those properties and check `.includes`)

Comment: in textContent ...

Comment: In checkInput function you can simply do, `var result = window.find(query); if (result) { return true} else { return alert('Not found!');}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2g37Lq1/) ,This code is similar to your code

```js
findString = function findText(text) {
  alert("String \x22" + text + "\x22 found? " + window.find(text));
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find -->

<p>Apples, Bananas, and Oranges.</p>
<button type="button" onClick='findString("Apples")'>Search for Apples</button>
<button type="button" onClick='findString("Banana")'>Search for Banana</button>
<button type="button" onClick='findString("Orange")'>Search for Orange</button>
```

Comment: how to change text true and false in alert notification ?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `window.find`. As [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find) says:

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Just search the `textContent` string of the document instead:

```js
document.querySelector('#submit_form')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const query = document.querySelector('#search').value;
    console.log('Found: ' + document.body.textContent.includes(query));
  });
```

```html
<form method="" action="">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukan No Hp yg Akan Dicari..">
    <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
                <input type="button" id="submit_form" value="Cari" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</form>
<div>text1</div>
<div>text2</div>
```

Try searching for `text1` and `text3`